# Adding a directory path to your docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to add a directory to my docker image. I tried the below methods. During the build I dont see any errors, but once I run the container ( I am using `docker-compose`) and get into it  `docker exec -it 410e434a7304 /bin/sh` I dont see the directory in the path I am copying it into nor do I see it as a volume when I do `docker inspect`.

Approach 1 : Classic mkdir

```
# Define working directory
WORKDIR /root

RUN cd /var \
    mdkir www \\ no www directory created
COPY <fileDirectory> /var/www/<fileDirectory>
```

Approach 2 : Volume

```
FROM openjdk:8u171 as build

# Define working directory
WORKDIR /root
VOLUME["/var/www"]

COPY <fileDirectory> /var/www/<fileDirectory>
```

Comment: Paste your `docker-compose` file please

Answer (score 2):

Your first approach is correct in principle, only that your `RUN` statement is faulty. Try:

```
RUN cd /var && mkdir www
```

Also, please note the fundamental difference between `RUN mkdir` and `VOLUME`: the former simply creates a directory on your container, while the latter is chiefly intended for mounting directories from your container to the host your container is running on.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it work:

```
# Define working directory
WORKDIR /root

COPY <fileDirectory> /root/<fileDirectory>
RUN cd /var && mkdir www && cp -R /root/<fileDirectory> /var/www
RUN rm -rf /root/email-media
```

I had to copy the  from my host machine to docker image's working directory `/root` and from `/root to the desired destination. Later removed the directory from`/root`

Not sure if thats the cleanest way, if I followed the approach 1 with the right syntax suggested by @Fritz it could never find the the path created and throw an error.

After running the RUN layer it would remove the container (as below) and in the COPY line it would not have the reference to the path created in the run line.

```
Step 16/22 : RUN cd /var && mkdir www && cp -R /root/<fileDirectory> /var/www
 ---> Running in a9c7df27116e
Removing intermediate container a9c7df27116e
```